# Subtable with aligned columns

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: subtable with aligned columns]

I need to preserver borders. Table below should start at ~ half the width of second column of main table.

Here's what I have so far:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.t1 td,
.t1 th,
td.t1,
th.t1 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr class="t1">
      <th>Item</th>
      <th colspan="2">Description</th>
      <th>Sub total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="t1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td colspan="2">some description</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="t1">Sub total</th>
      <td class="t1">100</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cebga04t/

But second invisible column in "sub table" is too narrow and can't figure out how to make it 50% of colspan=2 without affecting other columns.

Comment: In the image there are two separate tables

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the effect, I don't care how many tables are there realistically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `table-layout: fixed;` should make the job done. In this case the horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells.

Here you can find more info about it

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

So your table will look like this afterwards.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.t1 td,
.t1 th,
td.t1,
th.t1 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr class="t1">
      <th>Item</th>
      <th colspan="2">Description</th>
      <th>Sub total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="t1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td colspan="2">some description</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="t1">Sub total</th>
      <td class="t1">100</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```